# How would I create multiple VLAN interfaces on a 802.1Q and LACP trunked network connection on Solaris?

Tags: networking, solaris, vlan, nexenta, lacp

I've got a Solaris (Nexenta) NAS box that I'm trying to create multiple VLAN subinterfaces for.

Currently, I've got an LACP aggregated link set up on the 10.13.111.0/26 network to my switch (Cisco 3750). The switch port-channel interface is in access mode on VLAN 118, so the NAS only sees one network.

What I want to do is to make the NAS VLAN-aware and enable it to communicate on VLAN 118 and 999. In theory, to do this, I need to enable 802.1Q VLAN trunking on the aggregated interface, create subinterfaces for vlan's 118 and 999 and assign the 10.13.111.0/26 network to 118 and the 192.168.1.0/24 network to 999.

I've tried to do this in the past by unplumbing aggr1, creating the vlan interfaces with `dladm create-vlan` and then trying to plumb in the two new vlans that were created. However, when I assigned the addresses to the vlan interfaces and put the switchport in trunking mode, there didn't seem to be any network connectivity - I couldn't ping other devices on the 10.13.111.0/26 network from the vlan interface.

Have I missed a step somewhere?

```
$dladm show-link
LINK        CLASS     MTU    STATE    BRIDGE     OVER
igb0        phys      9000   up       --         --
igb1        phys      9000   up       --         --
aggr1       aggr      9000   up       --         igb0 igb1
pub0        vlan      9000   up       --         aggr1
priv0       vlan      9000   up       --         aggr1
```

Comment: What say "dladm show-vlan", "dladm show-aggr" and "dladm show-phys" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just do this to create the VLAN interfaces on aggr1:

```
ifconfig plumb aggr118001 plumb
ifconfig plumb aggr999001 plumb
```

I don't have a create-vlan option to dladm.  What Solaris version is that?

Comment: I'm on Nexenta, so snv134. I've managed to get it working with the vlans on a single physical interface (no lacp aggregation), but aggregation still fails.

Comment: That would explain it.  My latest install is snv111b.  So, plumbing the interfaces like above doesn't work?  That's how we've done it on earlier Solaris versions.  It's VLAN ID * 1000 + instance.

Comment: I would say there are some `plumb`s too much in the commands.